# Help interpreting a question about irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-explanation

I am asked the following:

If $p$ is a monic irreducible quadratic in $F[x]$, where $F$ is a field, show that $p$ factors into linear factors over $E=F[x]/\langle p\rangle$

However I am having trouble interpreting the second part of the statement.

To me it sounds like we take $p\in F[x]$ and then evaluate it on the field $E$, that is to say, for the second time $p$ is mentioned the coefficients are members of $E$, thus the second time $p \in E[x]$.

Due to how convoluted this sounds I suspect my interpretation of the question to be wrong. What is the correct way of reading this?

Comment: Thank you, I typed it out

Comment: $\langle p \rangle$ denotes the ideal generated by $p$. $F[x]/\langle p \rangle$ denotes the quotient of $F[x]$ by this ideal. The coefficients of the polynomials can be viewed as members of $F$ throughout. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Yes, your interpretation is correct. To say that $p$ factors over $E$ is a common way to express the fact that when you interpret $p$ as a polynomial with coefficients in $E$, i.e. as an element of $E[x]$, then it does factor.

This can be tricky to wrap your head around in the abstract setting. But let's consider $p=x^2+1\in\Bbb R$, so $F=\Bbb R$ and then we get $E=\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle=\Bbb C$. I am hoping that the last equality there is clear to you already, essentially the residue class of $x$ in $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ becomes $i$ because it satisfies $i^2+1=0$. Now, clearly the polynomial $p$, considered as a polynomial with *complex* coefficients, does factor over $\Bbb C$ as $p=(x+i)(x-i)$.

This might be much less confusing because you can think in terms of $i$ instead of the residue class of $x$ in $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ - however, once you walk through each of the steps in this particular example, it should be easier to generalize.

Let's write $E=F[\xi]$, where $\xi$ is the residue class of $x$ in $F[x]/\langle p\rangle$. If $p=x^2+ax+b$, then this means $\xi^2+a\xi+b=0$. In other words, you may say, $p(\xi)=0$, so $p$ has a zero at $\xi$.

Comment: Clarification, when evaluating $p$ over $E$ are the coefficients elements of $F$ or elements of $E$?

Comment: @Makogan I feel like I might mislead you by answering this question one way or the other. You consider $F$ as a subset of $E$, so the coefficients are really elements of both. Are the coefficients of $x^2+1$ real or complex? Both actually, they are integers even.

Comment: In a "correct" interpretation, the elements of $E$ are equivalence classes of polynomials in $F[x]$, thus if a coefficient is in $E$ it cannot be in $F$ and vice versa. I understand that what you mean is that we represent each equivalence class by one element in it, since $E$ is isomorphic to a particular subset of $F[x]$  but the level of formality I need for this question does demand I reason qith the equivalence classes themselves, not with the simplification of handling the representative polynomials of each class.

Comment: That seems a bit contrived. In fact, the composition of the maps $F\subseteq F[x]\to F[X]/\langle p\rangle = E$ remains an injection (prove it!), so you have every right to consider $F$ a subset, yes even a subring (subfield!) of $E$. You are invited to make this as formal as you desire to understand what is happening, however after you have done so (maybe a couple of times) I am sure you will agree that there is little harm in making it implicit.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$p(x) \in F[x]; \tag 1$

that is, the coefficients of

$p(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^n p_i x^i \tag 2$

all lie in $F$:

$p_i \in F, \; 0 \le i \le n. \tag 3$

We are also given that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$; in particular, $p(x)$ has no zeroes in $F$; for all $\alpha \in F$, $p(\alpha) \ne 0$.

Now suppose $G \supset F$ is *any* extension field of $F$; since $p(x) \in F[x]$, we also have $p(x) \in G[x]$, but in general $p(x)$ will no longer be irreducible when considered as an element of $G[x]$, since the "extra coeffiecients" available in $G$ may allow $p(x)$ to be factored in $G[x]$; a good example is provided by the polynomial

$r(x) = x^4 + 1 \in \Bbb Q[x]; \tag 4$

$r(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, that is, in $\Bbb Q[x]$, by an application of [Eisenstein's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) with $p = 2$; though we can't apply Eisenstein directly, if we consider the polynomial

$r(x + 1) = (x + 1)^4 + 1 = x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 4x + 1 + 1 = x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 4x + 2, \tag 5$

we can apply the criterion with $p = 2$ to conclude that $r(x + 1)$, hence $r(x)$, is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$.  However, if we adjoin $\sqrt 2$ to $\Bbb Q$, we find that in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)[x]$ we have

$r(x) = x^4 + 1 = (x^2 + \sqrt 2 x + 1)(x^2 - \sqrt 2 x + 1); \tag 6$

another, perhaps even more germane example is provided by

$c(x) = x^3 - 2 \in \Bbb Q[x]; \tag 7$

a direct application of Eisenstein with $p = 2$ indicates that $c(x)$ is in fact irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$; however, if we adjoin $\sqrt[3] 2$ to $\Bbb Q$, we find that in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)[x]$,

$c(x) = x^3 -2 = (x - \sqrt[3] 2)(x^2 + \sqrt[3] 2 x + (\sqrt[3] 2)^2); \tag 8$

$c(x)$ cannot be reduced further in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)[x]$ because any factor of degree less than $2$ must be linear, and the roots of $x^2 + \sqrt[3] 2 x + (\sqrt[3] 2)^2$ are complex, and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)$ is a real field.

The upshot of these remarks--what is germane to the problem at hand and to our OP Makogan's quest to properly interpret certain statements in the body of question--is that though the coefficients of polynomials such as $p(x)$, $r(x)$ or $c(x)$ may lie in a base field such as $F$ or $\Bbb Q$, the arithmetic operations implicitly prescribed in an expression such as (2), (6) or (8), may be performed in *appropriate extension fields*, and may yet produce resulting coefficients which lie in the base.  This notion is, in a sense, the essence of the idea that we may factor irreducible polynomials *via* extending their fields of coefficients, and of course this may always be done *in abstracto* by forming a field of the general form $F[x] / \langle q(x) \rangle$, where $q(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible.

Applying these remarks to the present problem, with the monic quadratic

$p(x) = x^2 + p_1 x + p_0 \tag 9$

irreducible in $F[x]$, it is also prime and hence the ideal $\langle p(x) \rangle \subset F[x]$ is prime, hence maximal since $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain; thus $F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$ is a field.  If

$t = x + \langle p(x) \rangle \in F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle, \tag{10}$

is the $x$-coset of $\langle p(x) \rangle$, then

$t^2 + p_1 t + p_0 = (x^2 + \langle p(x) \rangle) + (p_1 x + \langle p(x) \rangle) + (p_0 + \langle p(x) \rangle)$
$= (x^2 + p_1 x + p_0) + \langle p(x) \rangle = \langle p(x) \rangle = 0 \in F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle, \tag{11}$

so $t$ is a root of $p(x)$ in the field $F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$; therefore $x - t \mid x^2 + p_1 x + p_0$ over this field, and evidently the quotient is a monic polynomial of degree $1$; therefore there exists some $u \in F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$ with

$(x - t)(x - u) = p(x) = x^2 + p_1 x + p_0; \tag{12}$

this yields, upon comparing coefficients,

$-t - u = p_1, \; tu = p_0, \tag{13}$

or

$t + u = -p_1, \; tu = p_0; \tag{14}$

having $t$, we thus write $u$ as

$u = -t - p_1, \; \text{or} \; u = p_0 t^{-1}; \tag{15}$

then we see that

$(x - t)(x + (t + p_1)) = x^2 + (p_1 + t - t) x - t(t + p_1) = x^2 + p_1 x + p_0 = p(x), \tag{16}$

since

$- t(t + p_1) = -t^2 - p_1 t = p_0 \tag{17}$

from (11).

We thus see that $p(x)$ splits as in (12) or (16) over the field $F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$.